# Jquery simple redirect code based on country code

Tags: jquery, geolocation

I have find this jquery code which working fine

```
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
  $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
  $("#address").html("" + response.country);
  $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");

div id="address" (I cant add the  in front as I am new in stackoverflow
```

I would like to improve it and do something like this. I am not good on jquery/ javascript and I cant proceed with it.

If country Code CY & (document.documentElement.lang === "en-US") then window.location.href = http://www.blabla.com;